# How can I know which objects retain an object?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Is there any way to know which objects retain a target object?

Although using ARC, I don't know why an object wasn't deallocated when it should be. I want to find which objects still retain this object. But how?

I did try using Instruments, but there is no memory leak problem. I check the whole project and I don't find any retain cycle. How can I know which objects retain this object?

Comment: How did you find that there is some retain cycles in the code even though using ARC?

Comment: I don't know whether there is a retain cycles. But I'm sure there are some objects retain this object which is expected to be deallocated at certain situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the retain method and log the call stack. This will log the call stack backtrace:

```
- (id)retain {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    return [super retain];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this method in your classes you think are not released:

```
- (id)retain
{
    return self;
}
```

and put NSLog or Breakpoint there.

Unfortunately there is now way to display retain relation between objects.